# Android SearchView over android launcher icon?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Is there any way that search view (after tap/click) expands over android launcher icon like over app title name?

Or maybe, is there a way to change my title to look like launcher icon (like on sreenshot) with some custom font..?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using this code inside of my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` worked:

```
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setMaxWidth(5000);
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null)
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null)
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Note:

For me the Home Icon was not hidden by default as @MattT. suggested, so I hide it manually when the search is opened and show it again when the search is closed. Also note that `getActionBar()` requires API 14+.

If you're interested, before using searchView I inflate my custom layout:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_items, menu);
```

Where the layout (**menu/actionbar_items.xml**) is this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I have used in the past to create that type of search view. 
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/

Also the action bar should by default take your launcher icon unless you specifically set an android:logo attribute. You can also modify this programmatically using the setLogo() method on actionbar.